# Stop a youtube video playing through the ShockwaveFlash interface

Tags: flash, delphi, youtube, delphi-2007

I am playing youtube videos with the TShockwaveFlash component in Delphi 2007.

The component has many options such as play, stop, rewind, gotoFrame, etc and they work on a normal flash file.

However if I try to use them on a youtube video it doesn't work.

Does anyone know if this is just the case, if there is something that needs set for this to work, or if there is another way to exercise control over the playback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the video from playing you need to make use of the keyboard commands the you tube player recognizes to control the player. They are limited...

```
 Spacebar   : Play / Pause
 Arrow Left : Jump back 10% in the current video
 Arrow Right: Jump ahead 10% in the current video
 Arrow Up   : Volume up
 Arrow Down : Volume Down
```

So what you can do is use

```
 SendMessage(FlashPlayer.Handle,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_SPACE,0);
 SendMessage(FlashPlayer.Handle,WM_KEYUP,VK_SPACE,0);
```

to fake a key press and get the youtube player to, in this example, pause or resume play.